# How to run a test marked skip in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I want to run only the which tests are marked as pytest.mark.skip

In my Test class i had marked few test cases are marked as skip. Now i want to run those tests only

Comment: `pytest -m "skip"`. See [Marking test functions and selecting them for a run](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html#marking-test-functions-and-selecting-them-for-a-run).

Comment: You can only do that with a conftest. Use request fixture in conftest to look for skipped tests at collection time and mark them for testing. Will post code when I get time.

Comment: @hoefling it does select only the skipped test, and skip them... not very useful

Answer (score 4):

You could switch to using `skipif` conditioned on some environment variable.

i.e.
`@pytest.mark.skipif(os.getenv('FORCE2RUN_SKIPPED_TEST')!='1')`

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR

**conftest.py:**

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
parser.addoption(
    "--run-slow",
    action="store_true",
    default=False,
    help="Run slow tests",
)
```

**my_test.py**

```
@mark.skipif("not config.getoption('--run-slow')", reason="Only run when --run-slow is given")
def my_slow_test():
    pass
```

**command line:**

```
pytest

...

============================ 1 skipped, 1 warning in 0.65s ============================

pytest --run-slow

...

============================ 1 passed, 1 warning in 6.68s ============================
```

SOURCE: https://jwodder.github.io/kbits/posts/pytest-mark-off/#option-2-use-pytest-mark-skipif

KUDOS: @silentguy

Comment: Is there a way to modify this solution to run only the slow tests and skip all the unmarked ones?

Comment: Yes. Code: `pytest --run-slow -m "skipif"`